# How do you link customer to subscription on Stripe checkout?

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

The problem I have is that everytime the customer checks out, they have a new customer id that is linked to the customer's email.

```
var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_xxx', {
    betas: ['checkout_beta_4']
});

var checkoutButton = document.getElementById('checkout-button');
checkoutButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
    stripe.redirectToCheckout({
        items: [{
            plan: 'plan_xxx',
            quantity: 1
        }],
        customerEmail: 'test15@xxx.com',
        clientReferenceId: 'cus_xxx',
        successUrl: window.location.protocol + '//domain.test/en/accounts/billing-success',
        cancelUrl: window.location.protocol + '//domain.test/en/accounts/billing-cancel',
    }).then(function (result) {
        if (result.error) {
            var displayError = document.getElementById('error-message');
            displayError.textContent = result.error.message;
        }
    });
});
```

I thought the `clientReferenceId` would persist the Stripe customer id. Seems like that is not the case. The subscription has a new customer_id.

Comment: This is a limitation of Stripe's Checkout, it doesn't handle member management. If you want existing customers to be able to sign up for additional products, I recommend building a membership area on your application. If a user returns, they login to your site, you skip the Checkout form entirely and you can simply charge or start a subscription with their saved card. https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/create#create_charge-customer

Answer (score 0):

As described in the [documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/fulfillment#fulfilling-purchases-with-webhooks), the value you pass to `clientReferenceId` is included in the data sent via the webhook if the checkout is successful.

You need to define the webhook address in your Stripe Dashboard. Once the checkout completes, the webhook is invoked, so you can carry out all the steps you need after the payment is successful.

Answer (score 0):

As described in the Stripe API docs, all you have to do is set the `customer` key to the customer ID you want, not the `clientReferenceId`.
https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-customer

This was also mentioned in the answer to this other SO post: [Stripe Checkout Beta: Avoid creating new customer for every payment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55165793/stripe-checkout-beta-avoid-creating-new-customer-for-every-payment)

For better security, I also recommend you create a session on your backend and pass the `sessionID` to your frontend, and call `redirectToCheckout` with just the `sessionID`.